# OpenCV VideoWriter object is fast in some parts of the video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

Hi guys I'm new to OpenCV and I'm trying to implement a low light video enhancement feature for videos recorded using webcams.
For this I have developed a small script which takes an inputFile and identifies low contrast frames and adds gamma correction to it. I used the `from skimage.exposure import is_low_contrast` for this purpose along with Opencv.

This is my code for the above purpose. I am trying to save the file in mp4 format.

```
filename = 'video.mp4'

def enhanceVideo(file):
  print('enhancing video')
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
  out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), 20, (1280, 720))

  while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    text = "Low light: No"
    color = (0, 255, 0)
    if is_low_contrast(gray,  0.35):
        text = "Low light: Yes"
        color = (0, 0, 255)
        # applying gamma correction followed by smoothing to low light frames
        gamma = 2.0
        frame = adjust_gamma(frame, gamma=gamma)
        frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame, 3)


    cv2.putText(frame, text, (5, 25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8,
                color, 2)

    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

  cap.release()
  out.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output video is what I expect in terms of the functionality, but once the Video is written to the disk the areas where it's identified as a low light area is faster than the original fps rate. As a result of this a input video of length 27 seconds is of length 21 seconds after writing to the disk.

It will be much appreciated if you guys can provide a solution for this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `20` you passed into the `VideoWriter` as the FPS with the actual FPS of the video you are opening. You can get the FPS using `cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)`:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID'), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), (1280, 720))
```

Comment: Thanks, But still the problem exists. The low contrast areas are fast compared to the original video.